# How I make different objects from one class function?

Tags: javascript, class, object

I'm making a note-taker app.

The problem is....when I click the 'view detail' button which I created, no matter what button I click among these, it shows me the modal of last content that I made.

I believe it shows me the content from the last object I created from the class function. And the class function keeps refreshing the object.

I want it to show me the content depends on the 'view detail' button I clicked.

Can you help me? Thank you (I marked up ❓ on the code for I what I think the issue is so that you can read more easily)

```js
class Note {
    constructor(a,b){
        this.title = a;
        this.body = b;   
    }
}

submitBtn.addEventListener('click',run);

function run(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let newNote = new Note(titleInput.value,noteInput.value);❓
         
    addNoteToList(newNote);    

    titleInput.value = "" ;
    noteInput.value = "" ;       
}

function addNoteToList(newNote) {
    let note = document.createElement('div');
    note.classList.add('note_new_container');    
    noteNew.append(note);   

    note.innerHTML=    
        <span hidden >${newNote.id}</span>
        <h2 class="note_title">${newNote.title.substring(0,20)}</h2> 
        <div class="note_content">${newNote.body.substring(0,30)}</div>
        <button class="myButton2 detail">view detail</button>
        <button class="myButton2 delete">delete</button>    
    ;  

    noteNew.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('detail')) {
            activeModal(newNote);
            modalDetailContainer.classList.add('modal_show');
        }  
    }); 
}

function activeModal(a) {    
    document.querySelector('.modal_title').innerHTML= ${a.title};❓
    document.querySelector('.modal_content').innerHTML = ${a.body};❓
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `class` code is fine, there is nothing wrong with the instances, and nothing is shared.

The problem is that you are attaching the listener - *all* listeners - to the `noteNew` container that holds all the notes, not to the invidual new `note` divs. Clicking on one `.detail` button will fire them all, and the last one will win.